# Split invoice in pdf and excel

Tags: excel, vba, database, ms-access

I have an invoice in MS access table and the invoice needs to be split according to the subsidiary field.

```
Private Sub CreateInv()
Dim i As Integer
Set db = CurrentDb

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tbl_result")
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("tbl_result")

Do While rs.EOF = False
    i = rs1![Subsidiary]
    
    If rs1![Subsidiary] = "1025" Then Workbooks.Open CurrentProject.Path & "\Temp1025.xlsx"
    If rs1![Subsidiary] = "1028" Then Workbooks.Open CurrentProject.Path & "\Temp1028.xlsx"
    
    'Fill Invoice
    Range("B2") = rs1![invno]
    Range("C2") = rs1![vendorid]
    Range("D2") = rs1![Subsidiary]
    Range("E2") = rs1![InvDate]
   
    rs1.MoveNext
    If rs1.EOF = True Then GoTo Jumper

Jumper:

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "c:\users\nkumar\desktop\" & "sub2.xlsx"
    excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    excel.Application.Quit
    'excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    rs.MoveNext
    'x = 0
    If rs1.EOF = True Then Exit Sub
Loop

End Sub
```

Logic / Expected Output -> I have created two templates in excel. If the subsidiary is 1025 then write invoice details (table data) to Temp1025 excel file and if the subsidiary is 1028 then write invoice details (table data) to Temp1028 excel file.

Your assistance is much appreciated. Thank you in advance,
Nirmal

Comment: Every loop will go to jumper, ```If rs1.EOF = True Then GoTo Jumper``` does nothing since the next line is the label your goto is referencing. I also don't understand why you have two recordset variables for the same table while looping through them at the same rate.

Comment: What happens when you run your code though?  Most of your Excel-related code is written as if it were running in Excel.  You can't do that if it's running in Access.  You need to define and create an Excel Application object (eg) `xlApp` and use that to indicate it's Excel you're referring to eg. `xlApp.Workbooks.Open`

Comment: @Warcupine The Jumper I assume it to move to the next record with rs.MoveNext (to write the columns). I will change the two recordset variables to single recordset variable.

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes sure, I will create an excel application object. When the output is generated, the data gets written only on sub2.xlsx excel file and nothing is written on the Temp1025 and Temp1028 excel file.

Comment: You should step through this code to see what it is doing. A label is just a label, everything after that is run each iteration of the loop.

Comment: True, after Jumper, the data is written on sub2.xlsx file containing both subsidiary data of 1025 and 1028. I have 60 rows in tbl_result (data table) but only 10 rows are written. It's not getting written in the template at all.

Comment: Opening same workbook within loop of recordset makes no sense. GoTo Jumper within loop makes no sense. Writing each record to same cells makes no sense. Is tbl_result a temp table used to hold filtered dataset just for this process? Why write data to Excel at all? Why is PDF in topic? If you need to create PDF of invoice, use an Access report exported to PDF.

Comment: Do you want all 1025 records in one Excel file and all 1028 in another Excel file?  Right now your code write only one record to each file and then saves it over the previous one (well, it would if your code actually ran)

Comment: A filtered query recordset and Range.CopyFromRecordset method might be suitable approach.

Comment: @June7 The requirement is to write data from access table tbl_result to an excel invoice template. The PDF format of the invoice is in a access report. Should I remove the Jumper?

Comment: @TimWilliams No, 1025 and 1028 are like id numbers for employees. So, all the data from 1025 should be written to Temp1025.xlsx and all the data from 1028 should be written to Temp1028.xlsx. But, I am not able to get the data written to the template. The data is getting saved to Sub2.xlsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should look something like this (untested, since I don't have Access):

```vb
Private Sub CreateInv()

    Dim Db, s, rs As Object, xlApp As Object, wb As Object
    Set Db = CurrentDb
    
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Visible = True
    
    For Each s In Array("1025", "1028")
    
        'select only the records for this id
        Set rs = Db.OpenRecordset("select t.invno, t.vendorid, t.subsidiary, t.invdate " & _
                        " from tbl_result t where t.subsidiary='" & s & "'")
        'if there are records retrieved then write to Excel template
        If Not rs.EOF Then
            'open template based on subsidiary name
            Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(CurrentProject.Path & "\Temp" & s & ".xlsx")
            wb.Sheets(1).Range("B2").CopyFromRecordset rs 'write all records
            wb.SaveAs "c:\users\nkumar\desktop\Sub_" & s & ".xlsx"
            wb.Close False
        End If
        rs.Close
    
    Next s
    
    xlApp.Quit 'close Excel
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting datatype mismatch in the expression - Set rs

Comment: If `subsidiary` field is not numeric then you will need to add single quotes around `s` in the SQL

Comment: The code works super awesome when I change the datatype of Subsidiary field to Number. Is there any way I can get it working if the field is Short Text?

Comment: Set rs = Db.OpenRecordset("select t.invno, t.vendorid, t.Subsidiary " & _
                                  "from tbl_result t where t.Subsidiary= " & 's')

Comment: Adding single quotes around s still throws an error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223320/discussion-between-nirmal-and-tim-williams).

Comment: Excel is fine, but pdf writes only one record

Comment: For Each s In Array("1025", "1028")

    Set rs = Db.OpenRecordset("select t.invno, t.vendorid, t.Subsidiary," &_
                "from tbl_result t where t.Subsidiary= '" & s & "'")
   
    If Not rs.EOF Then
            Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(CurrentProject.Path & "\PDFTemplate" & s & ".xlsx")
            Range("L1") = rs![invno]
            Range("L2") = rs![InvDate]
            Range("C18") = rs![Description (Line/Item)]
                      
           End If
           'Next s
           rs.MoveNext